# iOs application icon, no as bright as on monitor

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Small problem here, I'm building an app for ios, and I've added and icon to my project 57x57, and 114x114, but when I run my app on the device, icon is very dim, when original is very bright. How can I fix it? Does it matter if I build my app in debug mode or release?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS adds a gloss/shine effect to your app icon that can sometimes reduce the saturation of your image. Add the UIPrerenderedIcon flag to your info.plist file as described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW16) to disable this.

EDITED to add iOS5 details

On iOS 5 there is a new key for specifying icons: [CFBundleIcons](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-SW13) is the raw name and it displays as 'Icon files (iOS5)' in the plist editor. To turn off the icon shine effect on iOS 5 devices you need to set the UIPrerenderedIcon flag on the Primary Icon as shown below.

To cover all cases (iOS3 - iOS5) you need to specify UIPrerenderedIcon in both places.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it actually helped, only I noticed one odd thing - I've added to my .plist "Icon already includes gloss effects", and set it to YES. No changed. I started searching, and found in my .plist "Icon files (iOS 5)"/"Primary icon"/"Icon already includes gloss effects". So you have to change it in two places now.

Comment: Good point about iOS 5. I've added details to the answer for anyone else facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to physical differences between your desktop monitor and iOS screen. Only thing you can do is redesign the icon and check the colors on an iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

Check the brightness setting of your device's display. Perhaps it's not "up" as much as you think.

Or, you can disable the "shine" effect that iOS applies to your icon by adding the "Icon already includes gloss effects" boolean to your Info.plist file. That might help.