# App icon displaying difference

Tags: iphone, icons

Below is my icon image and icon as it looks on the device screen.  They look different, can someone explain why?
[image]    [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove the gloss from the icon by setting a property in your Info tab of the Project setting in XCode.

Set "Icon already includes gloss effects" to YES to remove the Apple provided gloss.

Answer (score 0):

You have no choice about the rounded corners.

To remove the gloss you must make several changes to your app's info.plist file - one change for iOS 3 and 4, and another set of changes for iOS 5.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127768/ios-application-icon-no-as-bright-as-on-monitor/8127864#8127864).

Answer (score -7):

Xcode automatically applies gloss effect to the icons as well as rounded corners.. this looks better than yours.. :) You have any problem?

Comment: well .. i can write a full paragraph stating that i wasn't rude and other important facts... but what the hell...!! now i have got so many down votes..so it is time to be rude:) .. thank you all for your down votes..i really appreciate some of you would have taken -1 to give me -2 rep and some who will be going the extra mile to flag the post..i really appreciate it..makes me feel famous:) ..

Comment: P.S.. if you are really not a bot.. then please check his question and my answer again .. i helped him according to his question.. i just stated a fact..didn't mocked him ..i helped hime more than my so called rudeness..!! ..and then tried to ask his real question .. i would have provided him with the changes required in info.plist had he stated he didn't wanted it ..!!